# At least one digit, minimum 8 chars length, with unicode

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I know that regex questions have been asked many times before, but I just can't make it to work as I need. What I need is a regex, with a minimum of 8 characters, containing at least one digit (digits can appear in the start, end or after other characters), and supporting Unicode, so that Hebrew, Arabic etc. characters can be used.

Comment: Unicode support varies with each implementation of regex. Where are you using this expression?

Comment: [This question (and answer)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991212/how-do-i-regex-match-a-string-with-fixed-length-and-at-least-a-digit-in-it?rq=1) could help. You would likely need to replace the `10` with `8,`.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET. But it seems that Lucas's and Andie2302's answers work great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the basic regex:

```
^(?=.*?\d).{8}
```

`^.{8}` will match any string that has at least 8 characters. `(?=.*?\d)` will assert there's a digit in there.

As for the Unicode support, that's up to the regex engine. If Unicode is supported, `.` should match a Unicode character. If you want to match graphemes instead, your regex flavor may support `\X`, which you could use instead of `.`.

If you want to allow non-latin digits, you *may* need to replace `\d` with `\p{N}` depending on your regex engine.

**Update for the .NET flavor:**

- `\d` already matches Unicode digits so you don't need to use `\p{N}`
- `\X` is not supported so you'll have to stick with `.` or use a workaround like `(?>\P{M}\p{M}*)`.

Comment: Well, it seems that I forgot to mention that if the string contains only digits, the match fails, so 88888893 should fail.

Comment: @ashilon Then after the `^` you can add `(?=.*?\D)` or `(?=.*?\p{L})`. `\D` will require a non-digit, and `\p{L}` will require a letter. The full regex will be something like `^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?\D).{8}`

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming you are using a C# or Java like regex flavor, and you mean
>   with characters a character of the unicode category "letter" you can
>   use:

`(?=\p{L}*?\p{Nd})[\p{L}\p{Nd}]{8,}`

Comment: Thank you Andi2302, your solution works too. Seems that with regular expressions, there always are many ways to solve the problem.
Thanks again