# How to find a string with specified length that has specified letter?

Tags: regex

So, I know how to find a string with specified length and how to find a string that has specified letter. But how can I find a string that matches both conditions?
For example I want to find a 4 letter string that has letter "g".
What I did:
`\b[A-Za-z].[Gg][A-Za-z].\b`
this regex matches any word that has letter "g". So now I need to limit length, but when I try
`\b([A-Za-z].[Gg][A-Za-z].){4}\b`
it fails

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I regex match a string with fixed length and at least a digit in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991212/how-do-i-regex-match-a-string-with-fixed-length-and-at-least-a-digit-in-it)

Comment: Do you consider the cases where the substring contains only ASCII letters? If yes, the solution in the SO post suggested by naurel is not meeting your requirements.

Comment: I might have been in a hurry with my answer. In the sentence "azeGaze" has it to match : "azeG" & "zeGa" & "zGaz" & "Gaze" ? Or none since you're looking for a word (i.e. separated by whitespace), just "azeG" or just "Gaze" ?

Comment: Yes, I need ASCII only strings. In the sentence "azeGaze" it has to match nothing, since "azeGaze" is lonher than 4 letters.

Comment: what about the string `_azeG_` ?

Comment: _azeG_ is a string with length 6, so I don't need it.

Comment: then my answer is quite correct isn't it ? @stribizhev

Comment: @naurel: Might be, but it is too complicated for the current scenario. `(?<!\S)(?=[a-zA-Z]{4}(?!\S))\S*[gG]\S*` contains unnecessary subpatterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match only ASCII-letter sequences with length of 4 containing a specific letter, you can use

```
\b(?=\w*[Gg])[a-zA-Z]{4}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZ0pU9/2)

The regex breakdown:

- `\b` - a word boundary (we need the next letter to be a word character: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, but we'll restrict it to `[a-zA-Z]` with the subsequent consuming pattern)
- `(?=\w*[Gg])` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there is at least one `g` or `G` in the word (`\w*` matches 0 or more alphanumeric symbols)
- `[a-zA-Z]{4}` - 4 ASCII letters
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

Comment: Thank you! I will use slightly modified regex `\b(?=[a-zA-Z]*[Gg])[a-zA-Z]{4}\b`

Comment: It seems that the best way to check that in a lookahead is to use the principle of contrast. I'd rather suggest `\b(?=[a-fh-zA-FH-Z]*[Gg])[a-zA-Z]{4}\b`. If you can use modifiers, use `(?i)\b(?=[A-FH-Z]*[G])[A-Z]{4}\b` or `/\b(?=[A-FH-Z]*[G])[A-Z]{4}\b/i` (no idea since you did not specify the language).

Answer (score 0):

Already answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991212/how-do-i-regex-match-a-string-with-fixed-length-and-at-least-a-digit-in-it) by @Alan Moore

You just have to [adapt](https://regex101.com/r/jO6rT9/2) :

```
(?<!\S)(?=[a-zA-Z]{4}(?!\S))\S*[gG]\S*
```

> `(?<!\S)` matches a position that is not preceded by a non-whitespace
>   character.
>
> `(?=[a-zA-Z]{4}(?!\S))` further asserts that the position is
>   followed by exactly 4 letters.
>
> Once the lookarounds
>   are satisfied, `\S*[gG]\S*` goes ahead and consumes the string,
>   assuming at least one of the characters is g or G.

Comment: Note that this solution might be too "greedy" for OP requirements as it matches any non-whitespace sequences of specified length and having some symbol inside.